# Find list of procedures using a specific column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

If I provide the column name as input to the stored procedure  should I get list of Procedures and table names using that column from all databases?

Comment: Please specify the version of SQL Server. It's much easier to solve problems when we know what we're talking about, especially since metadata and dependencies have changed greatly between versions.

Comment: I've re-tagged. In the future please add a version-specific tag, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

for sql-server 2005+,  you can use :

```
create procedure sp1
    @columnName varchar(30)
as
    select s1.name,'table' type
    from sys.objects s1 join sys.columns s2 on s1.object_id = s2.object_id
    where s2.name = @columnName  and s1.type = 'U'

    union

    select s1.name,'procedure' type
    from sys.procedures s1 join sys.sql_modules s2 on s1.object_id = s2.object_id
    and s2.definition like '%'+@columnName+'%'
```

Comment: syscomments? Ugh. Try sys.sql_modules, at least the definition is all in one row if the procedure is > 4K. syscomments is there for backward compatibility anyway (and your answer wouldn't work in 2000 because of the sys. views you used).